# Find last value from one out of 3 row groups

Tags: mysql

I want to find a specific value from this table; the last value for each `ElEnd` that is has ItemNumber `2`:

```
ID  | ID2  | Item1 | Item2  | Item3 | Element | ItemNum | ElStart   | ElEnd
===================================================================
1   | 1    | rock   | n      | roll  | r       | 1       | 23.212   | 23.222
2   | 1    |  rock  | n      | roll  | o       | 1       | 23.222   | 23.256
3   | 1    |  rock  | n      | roll  | c       | 1       | 23.256   | 23.277
4   | 1    |  rock  | n      | roll  | k       | 1       | 23.277   | 23.290
5   | 1    |  rock  | n      | roll  | n       | 2       | 23.290   | 23.321
6   | 1    |  rock  | n      | roll  | r       | 3       | 23.321   | 23.331
7   | 1    |  rock  | n      | roll  | o       | 3       | 23.331   | 23.434
8   | 1    |  rock  | n      | roll  | l       | 3       | 23.434   | 23.456
9   | 1    |  rock  | n      | roll  | l       | 3       | 23.456   | 23.567
10  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | a       | 1       | 23.567   | 23.678
11  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | t       | 2       | 23.678   | 23.789
12  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | i       | 2       | 23.789   | 23.890
13  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | n       | 2       | 23.890   | 23.901
14  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | y       | 2       | 23.901   | 24.123
15  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | r       | 3       | 24.123   | 24.234
16  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | o       | 3       | 24.234   | 24.345
17  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | c       | 3       | 24.345   | 24.456
18  | 2    |  a     | tiny   | rock  | k       | 3       | 24.456   | 24.567
```

So in the case of this example table, I want to select `23.321` and `24.123`. I later want to use these values in an `UPDATE` to copy them to a new column `Item2ElementEnd`.

I've tried a number of queries that use subselect or `UNION`, but none of them were efficient - they were all running so slowly that I had to stop them (my table has about 600.000 entries).

This is a query which gives me the wrong value (ElEnd for ItemNum 3 rather than 2):

```
select ID2, Item2, max(ElEnd)
from t1
group by ID2;
```

This is an example query which didn't work because it was running WAY too slowly (I had to abort):

```
select Item2, ElStart, ElEnd
from t1
where ItemNum = "2"
and ElStart = (select max(ElStart) from t1 as f where f.Item2 = t1.Item2);
```

How can I do this most efficiently?

Comment: So all the other columns are irrelevant to this specific problem?

Comment: 1) Pls define `last value`. I have a guess, but a question should not leave any room for guessing. 2) Pls include what you have tried. Atm your question looks more like a "figure out what my problem is and provide me a copy-paste solution" type of question.

Comment: As it says in my question, I'm trying to find the last occurrence for each `ElEnd` that has `ItemNum` 2, so in the case of this example data, the values that would be returned would be `23.321` and `24.123`.

Comment: Repeating what's been written already will not make it any clearer. How do you find the last occurance of an ElEnd value?

Comment: That is exactly my question, I really don't know how to make it any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a (surprisingly simple) solution using this query:

```
select ID, ID2, item2, max(ElEnd), ItemNum
from t1
WHERE ItemNum = 2
group by ID2, ItemNum;
```